# What is global format() function meant for?

Tags: python, string-formatting

There is the `str.format()` method in python which I am familiar with however it does not work the same way as the `format()` function (global-builtin).

What is the purpose of the global `format()` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) formats *one value* according to a formatting specification.

The [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) parses out a *template*, and then formats individual values. Each `{value_reference:format_spec}` specifier is basically applied to the matched value *using the `format()` function*, as `format(referenced_value, format_spec)`.

In other words, `str.format()` is built on top of the `format()` function. `str.format()` operates on a full [*Format String Syntax* string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings), `format()` operates on the matched values and applies just the [*Format Specification Mini-Language*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).

For example, in the expression

```
'The hex value of {0:d} is {0:02x}'.format(42)
```

the template string has two template *slots*, both formatting the same argument to the `str.format()` method. The first interpolates the output of `format(42, 'd')`, the other `format(42, '02x')`. Note that the second argument in both cases is the format specifier, e.g. everything that comes *after the `:` colon* in the template placeholder.

Use the `format()` function when you want to format just a single value, use `str.format()` when you want to place that formatted value in a larger string.

Under the hood, `format()` delegates to the `object.__format__` method to let the value itself interpret the formatting specification. `str.format()` calls that method directly, but *you should not rely on this*. `object.__format__` is a hook, in future `format()` might apply more processing to the result of that hook, or pre-process the format to pass in. This is all an implementation detail really, only interesting if you want to implement your own formatting language for your object type.

See [PEP-3101 *Advanced String Formatting*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) for the original proposal that added `str.format()`, `format()` and the `object.__format__` hook to the language.

Comment: However I cant do format("hello", "{hello}") is that a special case not handled by format?

Comment: @Har: `{hello}` is a *template*, not a formatting specifier. The correct call is `format('hello', '')`; the format specifier is *empty* in your example.

Comment: The thing that confuses me is that Kikohs mentioned that format calls the string __ format __ method. So does this mean that the __ format __ method is not equivalent to str.format?

Comment: @Har: technically speaking both `str.format()` and `format()` use the `object.__format__` method to delegate how the format is applied. *This is an implementation detail*.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Martin's answer, have a look at the PEP3101 proposal:

> Each Python type can control formatting of its instances by defining
>       a `__format__` method.  The `__format__` method is responsible for
>       interpreting the format specifier, formatting the value, and
>       returning the resulting string.
>
> The new, global built-in function 'format' simply calls this special
>       method, similar to how `len()` and `str()` simply call their respective
>       special methods:
>
> ```
> def format(value, format_spec):
>     return value.__format__(format_spec)
> ```
>
> It is safe to call this function with a value of "None" (because the
>       "None" value in Python is an object and can have methods.)
>
> Several built-in types, including 'str', 'int', 'float', and 'object'
>       define `__format__` methods.  This means that if you derive from any of
>       those types, your class will know how to format itself.

[More info here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Answer (score 1):

**The str.format() method and the Formatter class share the same syntax for format strings (although in the case of Formatter, subclasses can define their own format string syntax).**

*Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces {}. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal text, which is copied unchanged to the output. If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}.*

**The grammar for a replacement field is as follows:**

```
replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
arg_name          ::=  [identifier | integer]
attribute_name    ::=  identifier
element_index     ::=  integer | index_string
index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
conversion        ::=  "r" | "s"
format_spec       ::=  <described in the next section>
```

See also the Format Specification Mini-Language section.

*The field_name itself begins with an arg_name that is either a number or a keyword. If it’s a number, it refers to a positional argument, and if it’s a keyword, it refers to a named keyword argument. If the numerical arg_names in a format string are 0, 1, 2, ... in sequence, they can all be omitted (not just some) and the numbers 0, 1, 2, ... will be automatically inserted in that order. Because arg_name is not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings '10' or ':-]') within a format string. The arg_name can be followed by any number of index or attribute expressions. An expression of the form '.name' selects the named attribute using getattr(), while an expression of the form '[index]' does an index lookup using **getitem**().*

**Changed in version 2.7: The positional argument specifiers can be omitted, so '{} {}' is equivalent to '{0} {1}'.**

As Mentioned in the Python Documentation